# FFMPEG Streaming Youtube Live

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php, fluent-ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I am streaming live video on youtube live using ffmpeg sdk

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(m_pAvFmtCntx, pkt);
```

av_interleaved_write_frame taking more than 60 millisecond  to write packet . How to optimize time?

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient information..
Anyway, if you write to `pipe` then it's more like producer-consumer problem. Check if other side reads output fast enough.

Comment: Simply this  av_interleaved_write_frame(m_pAvFmtCntx, pkt); method take more than 60 ms to execute while writing at youtube live video packet but it is fine with udp streaming